# how to get bluetooth address of your machine using C,Linux or commandline

Tags: android, c++, linux, bluetooth

I am a c++ developer.
I want to get the bluetooth address of my machine programmatically. I am trying to make a bluetooth connection between laptop (linux machine-server) and another linux machine(client) or android(client). I want to send BT (mac of type bdaddr_t)address of server to client (over sms or socket) where they can connect to server. The clients do not have display, so, can not check BT address of server from client side.

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you're looking for the IP address or the MAC address. Before you can start doing network programming, you need to learn the correct terminology.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcitool1.html)

Comment: You may want to use `hcitool dev` command to find the PC's bluetooth MAC address.
Make sure you turn ON the BT module before executing the command.

Comment: If you want to do it thru a C program then you have to use HCI library.
Refer [these](http://affix.sourceforge.net/affix-doc/x496.html) API's

Comment: i need the bd_addr address of bluetooth support, I guess it is the mac address.

Comment: I am using BlueZ API, and need to find bluetooth address of current device not the discovered device. It seems to be mac address of the type bd_addr